# Python application design

Tags: python, interface

I'm designing a Python application yet I'm unable to figure out how to setup the preferred coding interface I want for it. (The first implementation will not have a GUI.)

I want the user to be able to do something like in design 1, but currently have it implemented as in design 2:

```
#
#   Design 1
#
import myApp.core as myApp

myApp.new()

element = myApp.createElement()
element.rename("foo")
print element.name()

path = "C:/foo.txt"
myApp.save(path)
```

.

```
#
#   Design 2
#
import myApp.core as myApp

scene = myApp.new()
element = scene.createElement()
element.rename("foo")
print element.name()

path = "C:/foo.txt"
scene.save(path)
```

Based on my experience as an artist working with Autodesk Maya I'm familiar with working in a setup like in design 1 it feels very logical. It doesn't feel like you're running methods on a singleton class that represents the application. Instead it feels like you're always within the application.

With design 1 we could use 'from myApp.core import *' to get all the commands easily accessible. With design two it would be that I either need to have a singleton class that contains the functions as methods or I would need to 'feed' the global application into each function.

To get something working like design 1 I think it's something with global variables or something that tracks the application's state so the functions know on what 'scene' to perform their actions. Yet as I've so far managed to live without using such setups I have no clue on what would be the best way to go about doing this.

If there's a very good reason not to do it like in design 1 let me know and I'll change accordingly. As any interface it should be efficient and very easy to use.

Comment: Why don't you try that out? Yes, you need to create a global object in your module that the other `createElement()` would access.

Comment: Is there a typo at `path`'s declaration in both cases??

Comment: @Schoolboy: fixed the typoe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm not entirely sure when or where to instantiate the 'global' variable/class. Within Maya you would import the command in its internal script editor and it would run the commands on the application you're running it from. But you could also import modules that import the same commands module. There's likely to be more imports for that, thus multiple instances of the global variable if its created within that module. It feels like I'm missing the most obvious option. ;)

Comment: But `myApp` isn't a command, it's a class definition that you use to create  an `object` that you can then manipulate. Design 1 would be described as 'unpythonic' and so forcing python to work in this way would create many headaches for you in the future.

Comment: you can read the matplotlib source code, it has a function base interface and an object oriented interface.

Comment: @RoyNieterau: In Maya, the application itself *is* the global, the Python modules just give you access to that. If you need keep separate scenes per user of the API, then do not create a global. Take a look at the [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html), as well as it's [sourcecode](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fileinput.py) for a module that works both with a module global and the option to create a new object to work with if you do not want to use a global.